# DisplayAttribute turns off validation message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

So when I have a DisplayAttribute decorating a property in one of my models...

```
[Required, Display(Name = "Some Name")]
public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

I no longer get a validation message for the field when using the ValidationMessageFor helper

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SomeProperty)
```

And what's odd is if I use the overload that specifies a message, *I still don't get the message*.  Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Unable to repro.

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required, Display(Name = "Some Name")]
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SomeProperty)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeProperty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SomeProperty)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

When the form is submitted the validation error message is correctly shown if the field is left blank.

Comment: The only other thing I can think to add is that I have an editor template for the type (HttpPostedFileBase) and that the input is type=file.  I couldn't get it to work.  The field goes red (default css style) but no message.